# How to use sort function in list view flutter

Tags: sorting, flutter, listview

I'm making an app on flutter in which the items such as price in products List must be arranged in increasing order. After searching on the internet I came up with the solution of using compareTo and sort function but unfortunately, I'm having an error on sort() i.e: The expression here has a type void and therefore can't be used.
The whole proper code is on Github https://github.com/MaidaFarooqi9/Application/blob/master/lib/ProductScreen.dart
And the code part which I'm trying to modify is

```
return Container(
      child:ListView.separated(
        itemBuilder: (context, index){
          return ListTile(
           title:Text(products[index].name),
              leading:products[index].i,
              subtitle:Column(
                children:<Widget>[
                  if (!ProductScreen.name) Text("\$${products[index].price}",
                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.redAccent, fontSize: 20, fontWeight: FontWeight.w500),)
                  else
               Text(products.sort((a,b)=>a.price.compareTo(b.price))) ,
```

The if-else condition is showing at if() the unsorted list and after else the price will be in ascending order

Answer (score 5):

Just check out this example I have created from your given sample code :

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:percent_indicator/linear_percent_indicator.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  MyApp({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: SafeArea(child: SampleApp()),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class SampleApp extends StatefulWidget {
  SampleApp({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _SampleAppState createState() => _SampleAppState();
}

class _SampleAppState extends State<SampleApp> {
  var products = [
    Product("sample", 12),
    Product("name", 50),
    Product("azpc", 78),
    Product("hplm", 3),
    Product('ampl', 2),
  ];

  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();

    products.sort((a, b) => a.price.compareTo(b.price));
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: ListView.separated(
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            return Card(
              child: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                child: Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Text(products[index].name),
                    Text(products[index].price.toString()),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            );
          },
          separatorBuilder: (context, int) => Divider(),
          itemCount: products.length),
    );
  }
}

class Product {
  final String name;
  final double price;

  Product(this.name, this.price);
}
```

Let me know if it works.

Comment: Just make an upvote so that it gets complete and would be helpful for others as well.